# OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket (PYTHON3)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, chat

can't find a working solution to this problem, so I decided to ask anew.

**Error Message:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\New\pythonProject1\client.py", line 15, in 
> read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])
> OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

**Code Snippet:**

```
import socket
import select
import sys

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Correct usage: script, IP address, port number")
    exit()
IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
Port = int(sys.argv[2])
server.connect((IP_address, Port))

while True:
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])
    for socks in read_sockets:
        if socks == server:
            message = socks.recv(2048)
            print(message)
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(message)
            sys.stdout.write("<You>")
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.flush()
server.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike *nix, Windows sockets are not compatible with file descriptors. You can’t use `sys.stdin` with `select`.

Comment: What then can I use? Any suggestion, please?

Comment: @SamGeorge A separate thread perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean a new question? I have thread above I just created.

Comment: @SamGeorge No, a separate thread of execution to read stdin.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Tolonen. However, I am not sure how to implement that. Especially in the context of my problem. Do you mind providing any pointer? Thanks